# Calling a go script through exec in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, go, electron, node-modules

So I'm trying to make a GUI for another go project using electronjs and ive been testing and some things worked, some didnt, some did and then stopped. My biggest problem, which both i and my coworkers couldnt solve is this:
my main.js file creates an electron window which shows my index.html. index.html contains a button with the id="run-button"
it also links to a script "execscript.js"
execscript.js can call a go script, which writes a single word into a json file. (its actually gonna do something different, but its a placeholder because confidential info yada yada)
all the scripts work on their own
index button can call js, which is proven, because i put an alert in, so i know it works
js can call go
but if index tries to call js, which then calls go, nothing happens

this is the index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button id="run-button">run go</button>
    
    <h1>json file</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>notice</th>
                <th>license</th>
                <th>Commercial Use?</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="data-output">

        </tbody>
    </table>  
    <script src="summarytablescript.js"></script> 
    <script src="execscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the execscript.js

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

// // Select the button element
const runButton = document.getElementById('run-button');

// // Event listener for the button click
runButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
//   // Execute the Go file
  exec('go run main', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`Error executing Go file: ${error}`);
      return;
    }

    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
  });
});
```

this is the main.go

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    data := struct {
        Text string `json:"text"`
    }{
        Text: "amogus",
    }

    // Convert data to JSON format
    jsonData, err := json.MarshalIndent(data, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error marshaling JSON:", err)
        return
    }

    // Write JSON data to file
    err = ioutil.WriteFile("output.json", jsonData, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error writing JSON file:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("JSON file created successfully!")
}
```

main.js just in case

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

const createWindow = () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1050,
    height: 1000
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
  })
```

Comment: Since your go program is named `main.go`, did you try by changing this line in `execscript.js` to `exec('go run main.go', (error, stdout, stderr)`

Comment: yea that doesnt do it, but ive found a solution and will post it probably tomorrow